# Docker container on react frontend is not connecting with flask backend on EC2 instance

Tags: reactjs, flask, amazon-ec2

I have deployed react containers with another flask containers on EC2 instance, Running and connecting them together using docker-compose file, the problem is my react container is not sending any request to my backend container, i have looked inside the backend docker logs which are show nothing came from my react.

I debugged the problem and find out everything is works when i run my project locally.
The work flow is normal between both front and backend on my machine , but when I hosted moved on AWS EC2 they didn't work together.

This is my docker compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  frontend:
    image: omarsater/private-repo:react-v1.0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    image: omarsater/private-repo:flask-v1.0
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

[EC2 inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUA12.png)

[EC2 outbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPhWa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do run React application?

1. If you run it via NgInx, then you need add upstream in NgInx file with service name

```
http
{
  upstream backend
  {
    server backend:8080;
  }

  server
  {
    location /
    {
      #### Gzip Settings  ####
      gzip on;
      gzip_min_length   1100;
      gzip_vary         on;
      gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
      gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
      gzip_comp_level   5;

      #### Serve React Application ####
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    }

    location /api
    {
      proxy_pass http://backend;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For
      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
  }
......

}
```

2. If not, then it depends on how you deploy it.

Either way, you can access backend service using `SERVICE_NAME` in docker stack created via compose. I would advise you to test this in local and then deploy to EC2 for better clarity